# Sum column only if id is different

Tags: mysql

Hope everyone is doing well.

I have the following output...

```
+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| ord_num | signoff_date | program_name | prod_desc | tx_comp | priority |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+---------+----------+
| 1234567 | 2012-08-12   | ilearn       | run       |       1 |        1 |
| 1234567 | 2012-08-12   | ilearn       | plan      |       1 |        1 |
| 1234568 | 2012-08-12   | other        | run       |       1 |        1 |
| 1234569 | 2012-08-12   | other        | run       |       0 |        1 |
+---------+--------------+--------------+-----------+---------+----------+
```

What I would like to do is `SUM` the `tx_comp` column once per unique "ord_num".

Now I cant use `GROUP BY ord_num` as I also do a `sum` on the type of tasks.

Its like I need to know what the previous `ord_num` was then sum if different?

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

*** EDIT ***

```
SELECT 
    signoff_date,
    SUM(IF(prod_desc = 'run', 1, 0)) AS run,
    SUM(IF(prod_desc = 'plan', 1, 0)) AS plan,
    SUM(tx_comp) AS tx_comp 
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        ord_num,
        signoff_date,
        program_name,
        prod_desc,
        tx_comp,
        priority 
    FROM
        test.orders 
        LEFT JOIN test.tx_comp USING (ord_num)
) AS grp
```

Obviously not the desired output

```
+--------------+------+------+---------+
| signoff_date | run  | plan | tx_comp |
+--------------+------+------+---------+
| 2012-08-12   |    3 |    1 |       3 |
+--------------+------+------+---------+
```

I am after...

```
+--------------+------+------+---------+
| signoff_date | run  | plan | tx_comp |
+--------------+------+------+---------+
| 2012-08-12   |    3 |    1 |       2 |
+--------------+------+------+---------+
```

Comment: So you want two different sums, from different criteria, in a single query?

Comment: @MarcB yes that is correct...

Comment: "only if the ord_num is different" - from what?  The previous row?

Comment: @KeithRandall I only want to sum the "tx_comp" column once per unique "ord_num". My apologies if I am not clear.

Comment: is tx_comp *always* 1 or zero? And do you want the sum, or the count of non-zeros? Note that the second question only matters if the first answer is "no, not always"

Comment: @ctrahey yes "tx_comp" is either 1 or 0.

Comment: @mybigman Do you want to select last record in a group (by ord_num)? But, how will you select which one is the last? There should be a field to order records in group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the value of tx_comp is always 1 or zero, then we can leverage `COUNT()`, which may give us more options. For instance, we can count the distinct ord_num where tx_comp is 1:

```
COUNT(distinct IF(tx_comp, ord_num, NULL))
```

Which gives me a final query of:

```
SELECT signoff_date,
  SUM(IF(prod_desc = 'run', 1, 0)) AS run,
  SUM(IF(prod_desc = 'plan', 1, 0)) AS plan,
  COUNT(distinct IF(tx_comp, ord_num, NULL)) as tx_comp
FROM 
  test.orders
  JOIN test.tx_comp USING (ord_num)
  GROUP BY signoff_date
```

And there is no need for the subquery in this case. (**edit:** updated for your JOIN)

I have tested this with your sample data; the only dependency is on the semantic nature of tx_comp. You have been saying "SUM", and this assumes that the value will be at most 1 (I understand it to be a boolean flag, and in a comment on another answer you mentioned MAX(tx_comp) returning 1, so I think we're good).

Comment: What if tx_comp is different,  say tx_comp = 1, 2, 3 etc. and want to SUM instead of count.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use `MAX` instead of `SUM` on the `tx_comp` column?  I'm not sure about the semantics of your data, but I'm guessing that's what you want.  In fact, it may be the same for `run` and `plan` as well.

For that matter, what you *really* want is `BIT_OR`, as you're working with booleans.

Comment: thanks for the response, max doesnt work as it just gives the output of 1 for the tx_comp.